# Como fazer verificação com operações binarias?

Tags: comparação, binary, ciência-da-computação

Eu tenho uma aplicação em que separo os erros por *range*, por exemplo, erros de sistema de 10-19, ou seja 10 slots para erros de sistema, depois tenho erros de login de 20-29, etc.

Como é que eu posso fazer um `if` para saber que tipo de erros estou a tratar sem usar expressões regulares, só operações binárias?

Do género:

```
if( erro ==  20|21|22|23 )
{
     //faz qualquer coisa
}
```

Ou seja, se é um erro de login faz qualquer coisa. Se por exemplo `erro = 21` então entra no `if`.

Eu estou a fazer isto em Java, mas acho que a ideia poderá adequar-se a qualquer situação.

Comment: Desculpe ser chato, mas: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/176034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você deseja segmentar de maneira binária, uma possibilidade seria utilizar *bit flags* em uma prática chamada [*bit masking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

O funcionamento é bastante simples. Digamos que você possui 8 categorias de erros, e deseja reservar até 256 possíveis erros em cada categoria. Você poderá utilizar então um short integer (16 bits) para armazenar todos os possíveis erros:

```
Categoria         Erro
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Digamos que a categoria do bit 0 correspondem a login, e 1 a sistema:

```
Categoria         Erro              Dec   Descrição
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   257   Login: Usuário não encontrado
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   258   Login: Senha incorreta
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   513   Sistema: Falha na inicialização
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0   514   Sistema: Erro de configucação
```

Por fim, utilize operações AND para determinar se o erro é de uma certa categoria:

```
Se erro AND 256 = Tipo Login
Se erro AND 512 = Tipo Sistema
```

Uma das vantagens deste método é que ele permite a criação de elementos que se encaixem em 2 ou mais categorias:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1   771   Sistema/Login: Provedor Oauth não definido
```

Por fim, uma implementação simples em Javascript:

```js
var cats = {
  "login": Math.pow(2, 8), // Bit 9
  "sistema": Math.pow(2, 9) // Bit 10
  };

console.log(!!(257 & cats.login));   // erro 257 é tipo login,
console.log(!!(257 & cats.sistema)); // porém não tipo sistema.
```

Comment: Era mesmo isso que eu queria. Vou testar, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Bem, primeiro que em Java (e também C#, Javascript, C++, Python, entre outras), usar códigos de erro é considerado uma má-prática de programação. É para isso que o mecanismo de exceções foi inventado, para que os códigos de erro se tornassem desnecessários sendo substituídos por objetos que carregam informações sobre o erro ocorrido sem ter que poluir o domínio do valor do retorno das funções.

Entretanto, partindo do pressuposto de que por algum motivo você não possa simplemente tirar esses códigos de erro e substituí-los por exceções, então:

```java
 private static final int ERRO_DE_SISTEMA_MIN = 10;
 private static final int ERRO_DE_SISTEMA_MAX = 19;
 private static final int ERRO_DE_LOGIN_MIN = 20;
 private static final int ERRO_DE_LOGIN_MAX = 29;

 public static boolean isErroSistema(int codigo) {
     return codigo >= ERRO_DE_SISTEMA_MIN && codigo <= ERRO_DE_SISTEMA_MAX;
 }

 public static boolean isErroLogin(int codigo) {
     return codigo >= ERRO_DE_LOGIN_MIN && codigo <= ERRO_DE_LOGIN_MAX;
 }

 public void minhaOperacao() {
     codigo = ...;
     if (isErroSistema(codigo)) {
         // Trata o erro de sistema.
     } else if (isErroLogin(codigo)) {
         // Trata o erro de login.
     }
 }
```

Comment: Eu queria uma coisa mais baixo nível, com OR binário ou shifts...

Comment: @JorgeB. Você já é um usuário bem experiente por aqui e já nos encontramos várias vezes. Então faço a pergunta: O que você quer obter exatamente? Porque você precisa necessariamente usar OR binários e shifts? Me parece um exemplo do [problema XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/176034).

Comment: Victor tens razão, mas eu não sabia como haveria de perguntar isso, se soubesse provavelmente já tinha encontrado o que quero numa pesquisa. Eu disse na pergunta "só operações binárias". O que eu queria é qualquer coisa como o @OnoSendai respondeu agora.